# React useState: Toggle boolean attribute inside object - how to identify onClick source?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

This may be a simple question and I'm just missing something, but I haven't found an answer yet.

I would like to use `useState` with an object storing both `onChange` and `onClick` events.

With `onChange`, the attributes of `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` are provided from the virtual DOM.  That makes it easy to identify which parameter the event should be targeting.

However, with `onClick` there is no attribution of the element from either of these `event.target` parameters.

How can one identify which tag is generating an `onClick` event in order to tell the handler which parameter it should affect in an object of several boolean parameters?

Here's an example I created in an effort to be both as simple and complete as possible:

```
import React from 'react';

const initialState = {
    switches: {
        menuOpen: false,
        modalOpen: false,
    },
    fields: {
        username: '',
        password: '',
    },
};

export default function Header(props) {
    const [changeStateObj, setChangeStateObj] = useState(initialState.fields);
    const [toggleStateObj, setToggleStateObj] = useState(initialState.switches);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(changeStateObj, toggleStateObj);
    }, [changeStateObj, toggleStateObj]);

    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        let name = event.target.name;  // these provide values
        let value = event.target.value;
        setChangeStateObj((values) => ({ ...values, [name]: value })); // and therefore, this works
    };

    const clickHandler = (event) => {
         let name = event.target.name  // nothing here
        setToggleStateObj((prevState) => ({ [name]: !prevState.name }));  // no dice
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="username">
                User Name
                <input type="text" name="username" onChange={changeHandler} />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="password">
                Password
                <input type="password" name="password" onChange={changeHandler} />
            </label>
            <button name="modalOpen" onClick={clickHandler}>
                Open modal
            </button>
            <button name="menuOpen" onClick={clickHandler}>
                Open menu
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
const handleClickModalOpen = () => clickHandler({target: {name : 'modalOpen'}});

<button name="modalOpen" onClick={handleClickModalOpen}>
    Open modal
</button>
```

Second approach, with your existing code, try use `event.currentTarget.name` rather than `event.target.name`. The `currentTarget` should tell you which exact element you've attached the event handler.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It looks like you've added an additional click handler is inside the `onChange` attribute, is there a reason you'd recommend having two handlers, and not just directly targeting `setToggleStateObj({})`?  Also, having a handler inside the element causes unnecessary screen redraws, any idea how to do this outside of having the handler in the element? Thanks :)

Comment: It is just to use an anonymous function to passes `{name : 'modalOpen'}`. To avoid unnecessary  function re-creation, you can define a named function and pass it to onClick. But just realised you might want to try `e.currentTarget.name` using your existing approach. I've updated the answer to reflect the second option

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it